# Multiple Dialogs, second not displaying

Tags: android, exception, dialog

I'm trying to display a couple of dialogs when a button is pressed, one after the other, and can't get the second to display.  The first one is simply a development stub to replace a validation process during development...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  <snip>

  btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           <snip>

           VerifyLogin(userName, 
                       password);
        }
     });
}
```

...and...

```
private void VerifyLogin(String userName,
                        String password)
{
  boolean ok = false;

  if ((userName.length() > 0) && (password.length() > 0))
     ok = DevStub(); // <- Mimics server validation, allows dev. to choose success or not

  <snip>
}
```

...and...

```
private boolean DevStub()
{
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
     .setTitle("DEVELOPMENT")
     .setMessage("Login: Successful or Not")
     .setPositiveButton("Successful",
                        <snip>
                       )
     .setNegativeButton("Not Successful",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                           {
                              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                              {
                                  new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                     .setTitle("Invalid Username/Password")
                                     .setMessage("Try Again or Recover your password")
                                     .setPositiveButton( <snip> )
                                     .setNegativeButton( <snip> )
                                     .show();
                              }
                           })
     .show();

  return success;
}
```

As I say, this is only while I develop the interface, then the DevStub() will be replaced by a real login validation but I'd like to understand what I've got wrong here.  When I tap the  "Not Successful" button i simply get an exception.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the getApplicationContext() in the inner dialog but, then again, I don't know - any suggestions, please?

Logcat:

```
E/SKIA(12620): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
D/AndroidRuntime(12620): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(12620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c581f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12620): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:706)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:316)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at com.mtbsoft.wud.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(12620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm(12620): GC_CONCURRENT freed 148K, 4% free 13223K/13639K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

Comment: What are you seeing when you execute your code?  Do you see any `Dialog`?  Are they out of Order?  Do you have an `Exception`?  If so, what does the logcat say?

Comment: are you using two dialogs? i saw only one in your code....

Comment: @nicholas: Thanks for replying. I do see the first dialog but pressing the "Not Successful" button results in an "... has stopped" message.    anoopss: the second dialog is in the listener of the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a `Dialog` using an Application `Context`, it must be an Activity `Context`, specifically, the `Activity` that it lives in.

Try something like this:

```
final Context context = this;
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
 .setTitle("DEVELOPMENT")
 .setMessage("Login: Successful or Not")
 .setPositiveButton("Successful",
                    <snip>
                   )
 .setNegativeButton("Not Successful",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                       {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                          {
                              dialog.dismiss(); //you probably want to add this...
                              new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                 .setTitle("Invalid Username/Password")
                                 .setMessage("Try Again or Recover your password")
                                 .setPositiveButton( <snip> )
                                 .setNegativeButton( <snip> )
                                 .show();
                          }
                       })
 .show();

return success;
```

Also, note that I added a `dialog.dismiss()` in the negativeButton `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm, thank you very much.  It's also nice to see that I was slowly inching down the right track with my thoughts about the context but was a long way off your solution.  Thanks again.